# How do I keep my registered domain name to be replaced by my web host domain name?

Tags: web-hosting, domains

I registered a domain name, let's say for example `my-super-project.com`, and I've got my site hosted on, say `spproject.megahost.com`.

When I enter `my-super-project.com`, I get redirected to my site, but the address doesn't show `my-super-project.com`, but `spproject.megahost.com`.

How do I keep that from happening?

Comment: Does your host use cPanel?

Comment: @JohnD I don't think so, but to be honest I can't be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to contact the support for your hosting company to see how you can configure your site so that it lives at the my-super-project.com. What is the hosting company?

Comment: First, would it help? I mean the registrar and the hosting company are two different entities.

Comment: Yes. You configure your domain at the registrar to use your hosting  company's DNS server. You then do more configuration at the hosting company.

Comment: Ok, I read that my host supports only A-record and not Nameserver, C-name or MX records. And I fear that my registrar uses MX records (I'm not sure)...

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a URL mask to show the address as my-super-project.com, however, this results in showing the same url on every page. This is the problem I am having. I can rewrite urls using mod_rewrite in apache, but I can't figure out how to redirect my-super-project.com to spproject.megahost.com and see my-super-project.com/FILESTRUCTURE

I would love an answer on this. Sorry I couldn't be of help. You can see the MASK in action here.

http://www.charlottetheeditor.com

EDIT: I'd like to note that a mask is not search engine friendly either.